# Encrypt a DVD-RW?

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, disk-format, iso

While I can create an encrypted thumb drive easily enough with Disk Utility, I wonder how can I create an encrypted DVD+R disc which, when I put it in the drive, causes MacOS to ask me for a password?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Just to clarify, can we assume you’re wanting to create the encrypted DVD+R disc using macOS itself? Also, what content would be on the DVD+R disk? Are we just talking files and folders or something else? Finally, are you wanting a password to be required before being able to read the disk, or just required when a user actually tries opening files etc?

Comment: Just files and folders, the same as with an encrypted flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

*Firstly, I feel it important to point out that requiring a password to open a folder or disk does not necessarily mean that it is encrypted.*

Based on your question, I actually think the best way to go would be to just create an encrypted (and password protected) disk image via Disk Utility and then burn this to your DVD+R disk. This doesn't mean that macOS will prompt the user for a password upon mounting the DVD, but it does mean that macOS will prompt for a password when a user tries opening the disk image.

There's a number of options you have in setting this up, but I'm going to assume that you're happy for all the files and folders to be located within a single folder.

Follow these steps:

1. If they're not already, place all your files and folders within a single folder
2. Launch Disk Utility
3. Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> shortcut (or go to File > New Image > Image from Folder...)
4. In the window that appears, navigate to the folder you placed everything into at Step 1, select it and click on <kbd>Choose</kbd>
5. Give your disk image a name
6. **Note:** By default your disk image will be saved to the same location as the folder you selected, but if you want to change this use the *Where* drop-down menu
7. Choose the encryption method you prefer from the *Encryption* drop-down list
8. Enter a password and enter it again to verify
9. Click on <kbd>Choose</kbd>
10. Choose the image format you prefer from the *Image Format* drop-down list
11. Click on <kbd>Save</kbd>

Now you have an encrypted (and password protected) disk image file containing all the files and folders you wanted to protect.

Simply burn this to your DVD+R (or other optical media) and no-one will be able to access these files without macOS first prompting them for a password.

**IMPORTANT:** When you try to open the disk image, macOS will prompt you for a password. Below the password field is a checkbox if you want your Mac to remember the password in your keychain. **Do not** select this option before burning the disk image to disk and/or you want macOS to continue prompting you for a password!